# How to check for nil and initialize in the same line when the variable can be false?

Tags: ruby

How can I reduce this piece of code to be more readable?

```rb
@variable.nil? ? @variable = method_returning_true_or_false : @variable
```

I cannot use the pipe operator here as if the method returns false, it will still execute the method as shown by the piece of code below, which I don't want.

```rb
@variable ||= method_returning_true_or_false
```

I also want to return the value of `@variable` with this, hence

```rb
@variable = method_returning_true_or_false if @variable.nil?
```

wouldn't work.

Comment: I would go with `@variable = method_returning_true_or_false if @variable.nil?`, but this approach assumes you don't care what's returned from this statement, which I don't know if it's true.

Comment: @MarekLipka, thanks for answering, yes, I also care about what is returned from this statement, I've updated the question!

Comment: You could write `(@variable = method if @variable.nil?) || @variable` but I would not regard that as more clear. I'd go with two lines, your last line followed by `@variable`.

Comment: Option using `Hash`: `var = { nil => [true, false].sample, var => var }[var]`. Ugly enough? Readable? A more readable but verbose way is using plain `if then else`..

Comment: Why do you aim to have this solved in just one line? is this a code golf exercises? I would always aim for readability and write code that is easy to understand.

Comment: @spickermann No, this is not a code golf exercise, I have to define multiple methods that perform this kind of computation with changing conditions, and being ruby novice I wanted to check if I can define it in one line and make it readable too.
I'll go with what Cary Swoveland has suggested for now!